# nginx real_ip_header without set_real_ip_from

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to use `real_ip_header` without using `set_real_ip_from`?

My web server is behind a CDN-like system. They have over 1,000 servers and any one of them could be making the request. And their list of servers keeps changing so it's hard to keep all `set_real_ip_from` directives in sync.

Since I know that all requests will be proxied by their system, is there a way to use `real_ip_header` without `set_real_ip_from`? When I tried that, the `real_ip_header` directive was ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all those 1,000 servers belong to the same network / IP-range? Then you could supply a IP-range to the set_real_ip_from directive like `set_real_ip_from 10.2.0.0/16;`

To trust all IPs you can use `set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;` although this is not recommended. If someone finds out the ip of your application server he can easily spoof any IP.